# What information is exactly captured in console output and build artifacts in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

For example in the link below, on the left there is tab "Console Output" and in the center first hyperlink as "build artifacts". If we open these hyperlinks we see files. Could you please help me know what exactly is logged in the files?
https://builds.apache.org/job/Apache-Falcon-Pull-Request-Build/236/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Jenkins, every job have build steps, each build step can be anything from running shell\batch to trigger other jobs, evaluate conditions, and injecting environmental parameters. each step in the build can write output, all output is redirected to the console output.

The build artifacts are files\folders in your workspace that are created during the build (log files, test reports, each). files from your workspace on the slave are being transferred to the Master Jenkins when you archive the artifacts.

If this is your Jenkins server then you can access the job configuration and see which files you're transferring to the master. it'll be a step under post-build section.